# How Do I Properly Install/Access Javascript Library

Tags: javascript, php, html, chart.js

I am working on a basic website that includes php pages. I am hosting my website on cpanel. I would like to incorporate this Javascript library ([here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js)) into my project. I have downloaded the project, copied the contents from the source file into my project, and tested their example code ([here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started)), but nothing is displaying on my page. Is importing/implementing the project as simple as that, or did I miss a few steps? Thanks!

I apologize if I misused any terms, as my knowledge with web development is significantly lacking from other fields. Thanks!

EDIT: I am not using jquery/do not have it installed; do I need to add this?

Code below:

```
 <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1> Test</h1>

    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/chart.js" charset="utf-8">
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
    </script>


</div>
```

Comment: You do not need jQuery to use Chart.js. However, if you want to use a time axis, you will need Moment.js. can you post your code that should display a chart?

Comment: I have just posted a snippet of my code that includes the Div that I was hoping to put the chart inside. Please let me know if that is helpful, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

you can check this out because it worked for me. You were not getting any display because you included the source attribute in your script tag. What i know is that when you have a script tag while working  in a particular document and you decide to put some code between the script tags then you don't include src tag unless the code is in another file.Hope this helps.

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/chart.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1> Test</h1>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: I do not have jQuery installed (at least not to my knowledge?). Am I able to work around without it, or do I need it? Thanks!

Comment: @Josh D. i think you should have it installed since some of these libraries depend on it. Also load dependencies first before the script that really displays the charts

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Chart.js does not require jQuery, and recommending that the OP include jQuery just in case and without researching whether it's required is no-effort-expended.

Comment: @rockerest  thanks for correcting me